# Discord.js Codeblock format on embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Code:

```
  .addField(`:calendar: Created:`, `${serverinfo.created} \n ${serverinfo.ago}`, true)
```

I need help making the `${serverinfo.created} \n ${serverinfo.ago}` format to codeblocks, or changing the format of that to anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a codeblock in markdown, you can use ```` ``` ````, but, since you are already using backticks to contain your message, then you must add it as a string to your code, as such:

````js
.addField(`:calendar: Created:`, '```' + `${serverinfo.created} \n ${serverinfo.ago}` + '```', true)
````

To learn about all of the markdowns you can use in Discord, try visiting these websites:

- https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51
- https://bots.ondiscord.xyz/info/markdown

Comment: You can also escape the backticks with backslashes: `\\`\\`\\``